# "ChocolatesByNumbers" challenge

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

[Here](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoGK6AW9-Z4U/) is a problem I have attempted:

> Two positive integers \$N\$ and \$M\$ are given. Integer \$N\$ represents the
>   number of chocolates arranged in a circle, numbered from 0 to \$N − 1\$.
>   You start to eat the chocolates. After eating a chocolate you leave
>   only a wrapper.
>
> You begin with eating chocolate number 0. Then you omit the next \$M − 1\$
>   chocolates or wrappers on the circle, and eat the following one. More
>   precisely, if you ate chocolate number \$X\$, then you will next eat the
>   chocolate with number (\$X + M\$) modulo \$N\$ (remainder of division). You
>   stop eating when you encounter an empty wrapper.
>
> For example, given integers \$N = 10\$ and \$M = 4\$. You will eat the
>   following chocolates: 0, 4, 8, 2, 6.
>
> The goal is to count the number of chocolates that you will eat,
>   following the above rules.
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> class Solution { public int solution(int N, int M); }
> ```
>
> that, given two positive integers \$N\$ and \$M\$, returns the number of
>   chocolates that you will eat.
>
> For example, given integers \$N = 10\$ and \$M = 4\$. the function should
>   return 5, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> \$N\$ and \$M\$ are integers within the range [1..1,000,000,000].
>
> Complexity:
>
> - Expected worst-case time complexity is \$O(log(N+M))\$
> - Expected worst-case space complexity is \$O(log(N+M))\$

The results show that it's not that efficient. How can I make it more efficient?  What's wrong with my approach?

```
import java.util.*;

// you can use System.out.println for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int N, int M) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8

    int answer =1;
    HashMap<Integer , Integer> som = new HashMap<>();
    boolean check = true;
    int x =0;
    som.put(0,0);
    while(check)
    {

       int  m = (x+ M) % N ;
        x = m;
        if(som.containsKey(x))
         check = false;
         else
         {
             som.put(x,0);
             answer++;
         }
    }
    return answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

In these sorts of problems you can't take the simple approach, you've got to come up with a clever way to avoid actually simulating the eating of the candy bars.

Some hints for practice see how few hints you can use.

1. > Try printing out which bars are eaten and see if you can see a pattern.
2. > In your samples look at which candy bar is the first one repeated.
3. > You can prove this result by considering what happens after you've started repeating candy bars, and considering whether or not other ways of reaching the final position are possible.
4. > Can you express the rule for when the cycle repeats mathematically?
5. > Do you know the mathematical name for the first number that fits the rule?
6. > Its LCM

Comment: This [answer is being discussed on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2456/31503)

Answer (score 7):

Comments about your existing code:

- Your indentation is way off
- It is good practice to declare a variable by interface and not an implementation, so `Map<Integer, Integer> variable = new HashMap<>();`
- You're using your `Map` as a `Set`, so you can use `Set<Integer> som = new HashSet<>();` instead
- Your variable names stink (no offense, but really... why the name 'som'? why 'x'? etc.)
- Instead of your `check` variable you can use `break;` to break out of the while loop.
- Your `m` variable is only used to set the new value for `x` so you don't need it at all.
- Always use braces, even if it's only one statement you want to perform.
- Your existing comments are totally unnecessary and just noisy.
- It is better to only include specific classes instead of using `.*` in an import.

Here's the improved code, with all of the above fixed:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int N, int M) {
        int answer = 1;
        Set<Integer> eatenChocolates = new HashSet<>();
        int currentChocolate = 0;
        eatenChocolates.add(0);
        while (true) {
            currentChocolate = (currentChocolate + M) % N;
            if (eatenChocolates.contains(currentChocolate)) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                eatenChocolates.add(currentChocolate);
                answer++;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```